# Need some improvement in xml display

Tags: javascript, xml

i have implemented this code to display xml in html using javascript

current output

[image]

Need something like

[image]

Here is my code

```
function parseXML(R, s) {
    var C = R.childNodes;
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < C.length; i++) {
        var n = C[i];
        var f = false;
        if (n.nodeType !== 3) {
            str += '<br>&lt;<span class="nn">' + n.nodeName + '</span>&gt;';
            if (n.hasChildNodes()) {
                f = true;
                str += parseXML(n, s++);
            }
            str += '&lt;/<span class="nn">' + n.nodeName + '</span>&gt;';
        } else {
            str += '<span class="nv">' + n.nodeValue + '</span>';
        }
        if (f) {
            str += '<br>';
        }
    }
    var str = str.replace(/(<br>)+/g, '<br>');

    return str;
}
```

how i call this 
R : xml object
s : initial 0 (i am passing this so that i can display xml as hirarchical view)

Output in second 
- is not required 
i have post second out as it can be seen while opening xml document in firefox

please ask if any doubt

Comment: Please give us the input as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself.
Updated code with the solution

```
var pre = 0;
function parseXML(R, s) {
    var C = R.childNodes;
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < C.length; i++) {
        var n = C[i];
        if (n.nodeType !== 3) {
            str += '<br>' + gs(s) + '<b>&lt;</b><span class="nn">' + n.nodeName + '</span><b>&gt;</b>';
            if (n.hasChildNodes()) {
                str += parseXML(n, s + 1);
            }
            if (pre !== 3) {
                str += '<br>' + gs(s);
            }
            str += '<b>&lt;</b>/<span class="nn">' + n.nodeName + '</span><b>&gt;</b>';
        } else {
            str += '<span class="nv">' + n.nodeValue + '</span>';
        }
        pre = n.nodeType;
    }
    return str;
}
```